# How do I read particular tag in XML

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, struts2

Can any one help me in reading an XML which I'm getting as a response of a webservice call.

I'm getting a response like this ::

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<int xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">-1</int>
```

I want to preform actions when I get -1 as a response.How do I read it.
I'm using struts in GAE.I got this using

```
System.out.println("Fetch Content::"+new String(fetchresp.getContent()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different xml parser for different purpose:

- If this is the only value you are getting, which means `unstructured data` you can use whatever you want, like DOM parser ([DOM Parser Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)), or SAX parser ([Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)) or Stax([Exmple](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaXML/article.html))
- If you are getting `structured data` like a object, e.g `Employee`, `Student`, you should use `JAXB` ([Example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html)), probably offer a xsd to define the object you are transfering.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best way for you to go is JAX-B, a intro about it can be read here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 2):

Stax (Streaming API for XML) is an API for reading and writing XML Documents.

You can read more in this tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaXML/article.html